# Saving Screenshot file

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

My code for saving screenshot file is:

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\screenshots\\"+Filename+".jpg"));
```

**The Error is :**

> The method copyFile (File, File)is undefined for the type FileUtil

I use an `EventFiringWebDriver` . Any ideas on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible explanations.

1. The error message you provided mentions FileUtil class instead of FileUtil**s**  You may have used wrong class by mistake.
2. Assuming you are using the correct FileUtil**s** class you may have imported wrong package. Make sure that you have imported org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
```

I guess you missed one or more of these imports.. The code given above works fine for me with these includes.

Answer (score 0):

Plz put the exception then it will work fine.

EG: public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException

Answer (score 0):

public class Testscreenshot {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Images saved ..");
         WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://google");
        File scrFile;
        scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

     org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\Users\\R&D\\Desktop\\Tulas\\Javafiles\\testimages.png"));

        driver.quit();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`.
This imports the `FileUtils` class you need.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too what caused the error for me was that I added the wrong package

the package I needed to add was selenium:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.io.FileHandler;
```

but this is the wrong package I added:

```
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
```

so be careful when choosing a package.

Comment: It seems inaccurate to assume the error could be caused from importing the wrong package